# How to extract only certain values from a dictionary (python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say that I have a list l=[1, 2, 3, 4] and a dictionary d={2:a, 4:b}.
I'd like to extract the values of d only in the key is also in my list and put the result in a new list.
This is what I've tried so far:

```
new_l=[]
for i in l:
    for key in d.keys():
        if key in l:
            new_l.append(d[key])
print (new_l)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you do not require code elegance, then just change `if key in l:` to `if key in l and d[key] not in new_l:`

Comment: you have enough answers to get through , mark the one you seem fit to filter it from un-answered queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will compare each value in the dictionary and if it's match in the list.

**Simplistic answer..**

```
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> d
{2: 'a', 4: 'b'}

>>> [value for (key,value) in d.items() if key in l] 
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to cycle through each key in that second `for` loop. With Python, you can just use a list comprehension:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
d = {2: 'a', 4: 'b'}

res = [d[i] for i in L if i in d]   # ['a', 'b']
```

An alternative functional solution is possible if you know your dictionary values are non-Falsy (e.g. not `0`, `None`). `filter` is a lazy iterator, so you'll need to exhaust via `list` in a subsequent step:

```
res = filter(None, map(d.get, L))

print(list(res))  # ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip iterating `l`

**Ex:**

```
l=[1, 2, 3, 4] 
d={2:"a", 4:"b"}


new_l=[]
for key in d.keys():
    if key in l:
        new_l.append(d[key])
print (new_l)
```

Comment: This way round is somewhat inefficient as `key in l` has O(*n*) time complexity while the other way (looking for a list element in `dict`) can be done in O(1). It also doesn't guarantee ordering in line with OP's result.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the dictionary with key and match the key present in list.

```
L=[1, 2, 3, 4] 
d={2:"a", 4:"b"}

new_l=[]
for k in d.keys():
    if k in L:
        new_l.append(d[k])
print (new_l)
```